# Cannot receive App Store Server Notification or see transaction in xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, supabase

I'm building app for iOS with flutter and I encountered some problem implementing the IAP function.

### What I Encountered

I configured the notification server url in the App Store Connect. Then I make a purchase in simulator. **The product list was load successfully, the storekit poped up, and I finished purchase successfully as well.** But I cannot see transaction detail in the Storekit Manager in xcode, neither can I see notification send from Apple.

I'm sure I enabled Storekit in Edit Scheme.

[image]

PS: I'm using supabase edge function. I didn't see any invocation record.

### Purchase code

I use `in_app_purchase` to implement the IAP logic. Here is the purchase button:

```dart
InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
```

### What I Expected

I want to receive the notification from Apple when make purchase from both develpment(simulator) and production(physical device). Otherwise I cannot verify the user's purchase.

I tried to use 'verifyReceipt' endpoint but I was told this endpooint has been deprecated. Apple provide three methods verifying the purchase, but as I'm using `in_app_purchase` package I thought I can only choose server notification. (Seems that this package didn't provide other capacity except providing the serverVerfiyData. I got a transancationIdentifer as well but I cannot get any record using App Store Server API)

[image]

### What I Tried

I also tried purchase in my physical device with Testfligh build. I was told "You're all set", but there is no notification either.

The test server notification works just fine.